# Extract dates from text with spaCy in relation to a given date

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I want to extract dates, given in text form like `'next week'` or `'February'` from a news article, given the date the article was published. I.e. if the article was published on Feb 13 2019 and `'next week'` was mentioned in that article, I want the function to find Feb 20 2019 for `'next week'`. Does anybody know how to do that? I was thinking of doing it with spaCy's entity finder and then manually writing a function for every 'DATE' instance, but there must be something better.

Here is my example:

```
text = """Chancellor Angela Merkel and some of her ministers will
          discuss at a cabinet retreat next week ways to avert driving
          bans in major cities after Germany's top administrative court
          in February allowed local authorities to bar heavily polluting
          diesel cars."""
article_date = '2019-02-13'
```

My ideal result would be something as the following:

```
 ref_dates = {'next_week': '2019-02-20',
              'february': '2019-02-01'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SUTime from CoreNLP this can be done quite easily: 
https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime